# Java - Maven JAXB-2 plugin multiple schemes with different configurations doesn't generate classes

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea, jaxb

We are moving our existing project from Ant + Eclipse to Maven + IntelliJ IDEA.
I am currently using `JAXB` to generate classes from `xsd` files. I want to continue the current project structure so i want `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to generate the classes in a specific location. I have multiple schemes and want to generate the classes in different locations. I'm using multiple plugin execution bindings in order to do that as instructed in [the JAXB-2 Maven plugin site](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/example_xjc_basic.html).
My problem is that only the first execution is performed. None of the classes in the second execution are generated.
Here is my POM.xml file relevant part:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema1</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemes</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaFiles>myschema1.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <packageName>xml</packageName>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/example/dor/a</outputDirectory>
                        <arguments>-extension -Xcloneable -Xdefault-value -Xsetters -Xannotate</arguments>
                        <staleFile>${build.directory}/.jaxb-staleFlag-1</staleFile>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemes</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaFiles>myschema2.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <packageName>xml</packageName>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/example/dor/b</outputDirectory>
                        <arguments>-extension -Xcloneable -Xdefault-value -Xsetters -Xannotate</arguments>
                        <staleFile>${build.directory}/.jaxb-staleFlag-1</staleFile>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Update the version of your plugin, and, implement the maven fragment as provided by your own link

Comment: Thank you i didn't notice that. By "implement the maven fragment provided by your own link" you mean "Example 5" as I did before?

Comment: From what I can see, you do not need two executions, except when you want the output package of the two schemas to bedifferent. If that is not needed, you could just add two sources to the sources element in the same execution

Comment: The schema files are also different. Also from what i have read, the source element is for the xsd locations (input), not the generated classes locations (output).

Answer (score 5):

An update answer using version 2.5.0 of the plugin. This would be the configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
  <executions>

    <execution>
      <id>schema1</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <packageName>com.your.package</packageName>
        <sources>
          <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/sample1/sample1.xsd</source>
        </sources>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
      <id>schema2</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <packageName>com.your.package</packageName>
        <sources>
          <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/sample2/sample2.xsd</source>
        </sources>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
      </configuration>
    </execution>

  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps for newer configurations.

Comment: This worked for me. Just needed to make sure to specify unique packageName for each schema to avoid conflicts (com.your.package.sample1 and com.your.package.sample2)

Answer (score 4):

I would upgrade to 1.6, and you will have to put the 2 schemas in different packages to stop a conflict in the generated ObjectFactory.  Below works for me:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema1</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemes</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>myschema1.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>xml.a</packageName>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generated1</outputDirectory>
                            <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>schema2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemes</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>myschema2.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>xml.b</packageName>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/generated2</outputDirectory>
                            <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your advice. I will try to upgrade my plugin (it's a work project so no so simple) and i will update.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

Enabled the -X option of maven to see why the second generation is not performed.

The second generation was not run because the staleFile was the same. I had to add to both executions the parameter staleFile having different values:

```
<staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.xjcStaleFlag1</staleFile>
```

........

```
<staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxb2/.xjcStaleFlag2</staleFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using the jaxb2-maven-plugin version 3.x you can add

```xml
<clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
```

to the configuration section for each execution block. This prevents the directory from being cleared out after each execution.

see: https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v3.0.0/example_xjc_basic.html Example 5